# What is the way to export pinned tabs in Safari to a new Mac?

Tags: macos, safari, migration

I've an old Mac that I use as my regular driver with several tabs pinned (on Safari).

They're not automatically syncing on my new Mac and its just tedious to move them over one by one.

Any way to migrate these pinned tabs to the new Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way I found that worked:

- Go to Finder > (option + click Go in menu bar) Library > Safari
- Look for a file named 'LastSession.plist'
- Copy this over to the same location on your new machine (either via a USB or through a cloud)

(Quit, if needed and) Open Safari - your tabs should be right there!

*PS: Any problems with pinned tabs disappearing etc. are possibly due to an issue with this file.*

[Last checked on: macOS Big Sur - 11.5]